# Missing a Using Directive or an Assembly Reference WPF & XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am having a problem where, INotifyPropertyChanged, PropertyChanagedEventHandler, and PropertyEventChangedArgs, can not be found:

> "The type or namespace name 'PropertyChangedEventArgs' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WhackaMole_MVVM
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new WhackAMoleViewModel();
        }
    }

    public class WhackAMoleViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
    {
        private List<Mole> _moles;
        public List<Mole> Moles
        {
            get { return _moles; }
        }

        private System.Threading.Timer timer;
        private System.Random random = new Random();

        public WhackAMoleViewModel()
        {
            _moles = Enumerable.Range(1, 9).Select(x => new Mole()).ToList();
            timer = new Timer(x => RaiseRandomMole(), null, 0, 300);
        }

        private void RaiseRandomMole()
        {
            //If random number is less than 5 skip this iteration
            if (random.Next(1, 10) > 5)
                return;

            //Choose a random mole
            var mole = Moles[random.Next(0, 8)];

            //If it's already raised, do nothing
            if (mole.IsUp)
                return;

            //Raise it
            mole.IsUp = true;

            //Then Get it down somewhere between 1 and 2 seconds after
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(random.Next(1000, 2000)))
                        .ContinueWith(x => mole.IsUp = false);
        }
    }


    public class Mole : PropertyChangedBase
    {
        private bool _isUp;
        public bool IsUp
        {
            get { return _isUp; }
            set
            {
                _isUp = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsUp");
            }
        }
    }

    public class PropertyChangedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WhackaMole_MVVM.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Moles}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="3" Columns="3" IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image x:Name="Mole" Height="0" Width="100" 
                       Source="C:\Users\MonAmi\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WhackaMole\WhackaMole\mole2.png"
                       Stretch="Fill"
                       VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsUp}" Value="True">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard TargetName="Mole">
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" 
                                                     From="0" To="77"
                                                     Duration="00:00:00.3"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard TargetName="Mole">
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                                                     From="77" To="0"
                                                     Duration="00:00:00.3"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler's absolutely right. You need:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
```

... in your `using` directives, as [`PropertyChangedEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventargs.aspx) is in that namespace. (Or you could fully-qualify every reference to it, of course.)

The first thing to do whenever you get this error message is to find out what namespace and assembly the relevant type is in, and check your `using` directives and assembly references... just as the compiler message is suggesting, basically.